# Sparse table implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote a C++ implementation of a sparse table (I wrote it for an arbitrary function) and I want so much to ask for a review. I'd like to know how I can make it better, especially the consistency of the code and the design.

Explanation:

For example, you want to solve the RMQ problem with a lot of queries. You can precompute answers for segments, which have length \$2^i\$, and then give an answer for a query with the speed \$O(1)\$ (you need to compare two precomputed answers).

```
template<typename T_Type, typename Function>
class SparseTable {
private:
    static vs_ log_;
    std::vector<std::vector<T_Type>> sparse_;
    Function func_;

public:
    SparseTable(const std::vector<T_Type> &mass, Function func = Function()) : sparse_(), func_(func) {
        size_t len = mass.size();
        size_t add = log_.back() + 1;
        while (static_cast<size_t> (1 << add) <= len) {
            log_.insert(log_.end(), static_cast<size_t> (1 << add), add);
            ++add;
        }
        sparse_.resize(log_[len] + 1);
        for (size_t pow = 0; pow <= log_[len]; ++pow) {
            sparse_[pow].reserve(len);
            for (size_t j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
                if (pow == 0) {
                    sparse_[pow].emplace_back(func_(mass[j], mass[j]));
                } else {
                    sparse_[pow].emplace_back(func_(sparse_[pow - 1][j],
                                                    sparse_[pow - 1][std::min(j + (1 << (pow - 1)),
                                                                              len - 1)]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inline T_Type get(size_t left, size_t right) const {
        return func_(sparse_[log_[right - left]][left],
                     sparse_[log_[right - left]][right - (1 << log_[right - left])]);
    }
};

template<typename T_Type, typename Function> vs_
        SparseTable<T_Type, Function>::log_ {0, 0, 1, 1};
```

An example:

```
template<typename T_Type>
struct TwoVarMax {
    inline T_Type operator()(const T_Type &lhs, const T_Type &rhs) const {
        return std::max(lhs, rhs);
    }
};

std::vector<int> vec{5, 3, 7};
SparseTable<int, TwoVarMax<int>> sparse(vec);
std::cout << sparse.get(0, 1) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.